# Is this a valid git workflow to avoid auto-merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

```
git merge other_branch -s ours --no-commit --no-ff
git difftool other_branch
*manually merge all relevant files*
git add .
git commit -m "merged with other_branch"
```

Is this an acceptable workflow for a merge on which I want to absolutely avoid any auto-merging and do everything manually?

Will this merge be correctly registered as a merge in the repo's history?

Comment: Why not try it and see? Copy your repository and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely avoid any auto-merging by putting and committing a .gitattributes file in the root of your working directory with following content:

```
* -merge
```

This will leave the "local" version untouched during merge, but it will mark the file as conflicted when it was changed on both sides. You will then have to resolve each and every conflict on your own - no guessing by git.

See [gitattributes Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) section "Performing a three-way-merge".

You can then use your favorite merge tool as usual, but keep in mind that some mergetools silently resolve "primitive" conflicts on their own. Then you have simply pushed your problem one step further - git won't resolve primitive conflicts anymore, but the mergetool will do. Look for an option in your mergetool to avoid this. If you are using KDiff3, for example, you can go to the options, "Integration" tab and add "--auto" to the "Command line options to ignore" option.